# dimension of vector subspace of $\ker(T)\cap T(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ and $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation. I want to find the dimension of subspace of $\ker(T)\cap T(V)$. Is it equal to $\dim T(V)-\dim T^2(V)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We indeed have the following:
$$
\dim [\ker(T) \cap T(V)] = \dim T(V) - \dim T^2(V)
$$
To see that this is the case: note that $\ker(T) \cap T(V)$ can be characterized as the kernel of $T|_{T(V)}$ (the restriction of $T$ to $T(V)$).  Applying the rank-nullity theorem to $T|_{T(V)}:T(V) \to T(V)$, we have
$$
\dim [\ker(T) \cap T(V)] = \dim \ker T|_{T(V)} = \dim T(V) - \dim T(T(V))
$$
as desired.